# Proof that a function sequence does not converge uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of functions defined as :

$f_n(t) = \cases{0 & for $t \leq 0$ \\
                 t^n & for $0 < t < 1$\\
                 1 & for $t \geq1$ \\
}$

Pointwise, it converges to

$f(t) = \cases{0 & for $t < 1$\\                 
                 1 & for $t \geq 1$ \\
}$

But how can you show (formally) that it does not converge uniformly?

Comment: What results do you know about uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2):

The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is again continuous, but the $\{f_n\}$ are continuous while $f$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the convergence is uniform. Choose $\epsilon = \frac 12$. There must exist $N$ so that $n \ge N$ implies $|f_n(t) - f(t)| < \frac 12$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. In particular you must have $t^N < \frac 12$ for all $t \in [0,1)$. This is false for any $N \in \mathbf N$.

Comment: Right, this works for the f(t) in my question [0 for t<1, 1 for t>=1], but I think my question wasn't clear - what I really want to know is how can you prove that the f_n's don't converge to *any* function f(t). I guess it would be some modification of your proof, but if f(t) is arbitrary, I'm not sure how to complete it..

Comment: If the sequence did converge uniformly, it would have to converge to its pointwise limit. There is no other candidate for the limit function $f$ other than the one you supplied.